# Halachot when the groom has been previously married

Tags: halacha, marriage, wedding, contemporary-halacha, chupah

Are there any differences in halachot or minhagim in the wedding ceremony or sheva brachot when the groom has been previously married (and divorced), but the bride has not been?

Comment: From what I’ve heard, the 2nd time is that it should be a small simcha occasion. But Sheva brachos is observed all seven days.

Comment: See Nitei Gavriel Nisuin

Comment: I remember someone didnt make an aufruf but I think this is wrong. I mean he didnt make a big fuss like a 'bafarfung'. Throwing nuts or sweets.

Comment: Yes ,that is mentioned in Nitei Gavriel,talks about who accompanies to the chuppah and so on...